# Is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

> Is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]$ ?

The properties that  I learnt i.e. compactness,connectedness etc don't allow me to answer the question .Please help.

I have only learnt point set topology.Is it possible to answer this question using that only.

Comment: My point-set topology professor was fond of this question.  I don't remember an answer, but it's more difficult than it seems.

Comment: I think you should ask for a specific $m,n$ to get a better answer

Comment: For an infinite cardinal $m$ one can prove that the weight of $[0,1]^m$ is $m$, where the *weight* of a space is the minimum cardinality of a base for the space. Since the weight is a topological invariant, this takes care of the case in which $m$ and $n$ are both infinite, or one is finite and the other is uncountable.

Comment: For $m=2$ and $n>2$, you can draw a line threw $[0,1]^2$ which makes it disconnected, whereas the image of the line doesn't make $[0,1]^n$ disconnected.

Comment: The result for finite $m$ and $n$ is quite difficult; the usual argument uses techniques from algebraic topology. The case $m=2,n=3$, however, can be done with the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: @Nicolas: It’s not so easy to prove that an image of $[0,1]$ in $[0,1]^n$ for $n>2$ does not disconnect $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: Immersing them in a higher-dimensional topological space it is clear that if they are homeomorphic their interiors are homeomorphic. This is equivalent to R^m is homeomorphic to R^n. This is well-known.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS That requires proof.  There are space-filling curves (though their inverses are not continuous).

Comment: Why don't you try moving this over to real finite dimensional vector spaces (which induce a topological space). Then you just need to show that only your linear transformations are homeomorphisms (is this true?)

Comment: Per @Alephnull's observation, possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697596/proof-of-theres-no-homeomorphism-between-euclidean-spaces

Comment: @BrianM.Scott;Should I delete the question and post it like *Is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times [0,1]\times [0,1]$*?

Comment: Can I get better response then @BrianM.Scott;as stated in comments

Comment: @Amartya: Yes, if you want a proof that uses only general topology, it would probably be a good idea to ask specifically about the $m=2,n=3$ case. There probably still isn’t a *very* elementary proof, but you at least stand a chance of getting something usable.

Comment: Consider the possibilities when you delete a homeomorphic subset of [0,1]^2 . What happens when you delete [0,1]^2 from [0,1]^3 ?

Comment: One can use dimension theory and then Brouwer's fixed point theorem can be used to show that $\dim([0,1]^m)  = m$ for natural $m$ and as $\dim$ is a topological invariant, this settles the homeomorphism question.

Answer (score 1):

It may turn out that the easiest way to prove $[0,1]^2$ and $[0,1]^3$ aren't homeomorphic is to note

1. For any point $p \in [0,1]^3$, the space $[0,1]^3 \setminus \{p\}$ is simply connected.
2. The space $[0,1]^2 \setminus \{p\}$ is **not** simply connected for any point in the interior of the square.

Point 1 is easy to prove. Unforunately, point 2 takes a bit more than just the basic ideas of point set topology.

Another potential strategy: note that the "boundary" of $[0,1]^2$ is a 1d square, whereas the "boundary" of $[0,1]^3$ is a 2d cube. We can tell the difference between a 1d square and a 2d cube by noting that the removal of two points can disconnect the former, but not the latter.

Unforunately, it is not clear how to characterize topologically the points on the boundary. For $[0,1]^2$, we can characterize the boundary points as the points $p$ such that $[0,1]^2 \setminus \{p\}$ is simply connected, but this again uses ideas beyond basic point set topology. Also, if simply connectedness were OK to be used, then we could simply use the first proof outlined above.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know terms like "simply connected","1d","2d" etc.;So I could not accept your answer